# How do I read data from a textfile and append it to options of a select tag

Tags: html, css

I have a textfile in my project structure with 10 lines of names

```
Sarah
Adam
John
Connor
...
```

And I want to append all those lines as options to my as options

```
<select id="nameSelect">
    <!-- I want them here -->
</select>
```

my question is.. Would I use pure JavaScript or something like React?
Because what if I wanted to add 100 items to the `select`, I wouldn't want to hardcode each option.

Comment: You'd need to use server-side for this (Node.JS/PHP are simple examples). Do you want an answer using these technologies?

Comment: I've only heard bad things about PHP so I guess Node.JS would be better haha

Comment: No problem. Answering in progress...

Comment: You can't read from the HDD JavaScript only runs in the browser, otherwise refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654544/7148391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way of doing it with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org), a popular server-side framework based on JavaScript. The page will be stored at the URL `http://localhost:8080`:

```
//For the purposes of this answer, your text file is called names.txt

var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("names.txt", function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write("<select id='nameSelect'">
        var namesArray = data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
            res.write("<option value='" + namesArray[i] + "'>" + namesArray[i] + "</option>");
         }
         res.write("</select>");
         res.end();
     });
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text file *and* the file with your options are on the same server, you can indeed show the options based on the text file's content using only JavaScript in the frontend. When your page loads use Ajax to retrieve the file content, and in your callback split by newline and add each line as an option.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var select = document.getElementById("nameSelect"),
            options = client.responseText.split("\n"),
            i,
            _html = "";
        for ( i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
            _html += "<option value=" + options[i] +">" + options[i] + "</option>";
        }
        select.innerHTML = _html;
    }
    client.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: *If the text file and the file with your options are on the same server* I thought there would only be 1 textfile, the one in my project structure

Comment: @VargaDev by file with your options I meant the file containing your HTML select tag, in which you needed to put the options. JBDouble05 gives the best answer if you are able to do this server side. You would use Ajax if you were constrained to the front end.